# Can someone prove the statement related to convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to prove the statement:

$f$ is convex on $\Bbb{R}^n$ $\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad$ $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}^n,y\in \Bbb{R}^n$ and $\theta$ with $0\le\theta\le1$,  $\phi(\theta)=f(\theta x+(1-\theta) y)$ is convex.

Is there any simple proof?

I have proved this using convex function's definition, but it is so long.

I think there may exist concise proof!!

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of this in terms of ideas rather than formulae. $\phi(\theta)$ is a function that, for fixed $x$ and $y$, goes a certain distance along the line between $x$ and $y$ and checks the value of the original function at that point. When we take $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and draw a line between them and check the value at a point on that line, we can construct an $x'$ and a $y'$ that correspond to the location specified by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and check the value of $f$ on the corresponding point on *that* line and get the same number back. Since $f$ is convex, it then follows that $\phi$ is convex.

If this idea is clear, it shouldn't be too hard to just sit down and write the inequality that demonstrates convexity.

Comment: Oh, good explanation for understanding in geographical idea!!! But, if I answer like this, maybe.... my professor gives me low score.  :(

Comment: @Danny_Kim All I've done is state a chain inequality in words so that the formalism doesn't get in the way of the idea. Follow these words and write each sentence down formally and you will be approximately done.